# How to get XA-connections from SQLServerXADataSource

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, xa

I'm trying to understand a legacy application I'm working on, specifically how it deals with XA-transactions across two databases on different locations.

The application is based on JavaEE running on Payara (Glassfish) and uses jdbc to communicate with the databases.

The code uses `SQLServerXADataSource` to obtain connections, but this class provides multiple methods to obtain connections: `getXAConnection()` provided by the class itself, `getPooledConnection()` inherited from `SQLServerConnectionPoolDataSource` and `getConnection()` inherited from `SQLServerDataSource`. But, which one is supposed to be used when dealing with XA-transactions?

The code uses `SQLServerXADataSource.getConnection()` at the moment, but I can't understand how this will result in a XA-ready connection, as it comes from a data source that seemingly knows nothing of XA. I have seen examples online where `SQLServerXADataSource.getXAConnection().getConnection()` is used, will this be more correct when working with XA-transactions?

Comment: User code shouldn't normally obtain `XAConnection` nor use a `XADataSource` directly. They should obtain a connection from a `javax.sql.DataSource` that is managed by a transaction manager (eg from your Java EE application server). The transaction manager is what uses the `XADataSource` to get `XAConnection` and `Connection`: user code shouldn't touch that and only interact with a `java.sql.Connection`.

Comment: In short, if your code directly uses `XADataSource` and `XAConnection`, you are either doing something wrong, or you are maintaining your own transaction manager.

Comment: In any case, given your description, you don't seem to be using XA in any way (`getConnection()` is provided by `SQLServerDataSource`), and calling `getXAConnection().getConnection()` is definitely not how you obtain a properly working XA connection (and might cause connection leaks). Either configure and use XA correctly through Payara, or switch to `SQLServerDataSource` (though I would recommend configure through Payara as well, that way you might actually get a connection pool).